# nested string-join() expression

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have xml like this :

```
let $xml :=
 <info>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>one</name>
    <title>t1</title>
</info>
<info>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>two</name>
    <title>t2</title>
</info>
<info>
    <id>3</id>
    <name>three</name>
    <title>t3</title>
</info>
<info>
    <id>4</id>
    <name>four</name>
    <title>t4</title>
</info>
```

I want to transform it to `1,one,t1&2,two,t2&3,three,t3&4,four,t4`

what I did so far and tested on http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi is something like this :

```
let $sources := $xml/info
{
for $out in $sources
 return fn:concat(string-join(string-join(fn:string($out/*),',')),'&amp;')
}
```

now I want to declare it as a function in my file so I did :

```
declare function local:concatComplexDelimited($ReqNode as node(),
                                              $InnerDilimeter as xs:string,
                                              $OuterDelimiter as xs:string) as xs:string {
let $dsf := $ReqNode/ns1:path/ns1:ToMySequence
for $infx in $dsf
  return fn:concat(fn:string-join(fn:string-join(fn:string($infx/*/text()),$InnerDilimeter)),$OuterDelimiter)
};
```

It gives an error `string-join() unknown function or number of arguments` .. can any one help with the issue

Comment: It seems that your XQuery code snippets refer to different XML inputs. Could you possibly update either the XML document or one of the code examples? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information.

Comment: done ..I just assigned the xml to variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function declares that you will return a single string, but you have a FLWOR that is iterating over a sequence of elements and producing a string for each one and will be generating a sequence of strings. Plus, you are giving a sequence of `text()` nodes to `fn:string()` - who's values should already be atomized to a string when used as a parameter for `fn:string-join()`.

Change it to generate the comma delimited string with the `$innerDelimiter` for each `<info>` element, and then join those strings with the `$OuterDelimiter`.

```
declare function local:concatComplexDelimited(
  $ReqNode as node(),
  $InnerDelimiter as xs:string,
  $OuterDelimiter as xs:string) 
as xs:string 
{
  fn:string-join(
    for $info in $ReqNode/ns1:path/ns1:ToMySequence
    return 
      fn:string-join($info/*/text(), $InnerDelimiter),
    $OuterDelimiter)
};
```

If it helps to make it more readable, you could assign the inner lines to a variable:

```
declare function local:concatComplexDelimited(
  $ReqNode as node(),
  $InnerDelimiter as xs:string,
  $OuterDelimiter as xs:string) 
as xs:string 
{
  let $lines :=
      for $info in $ReqNode/ns1:path/ns1:ToMySequence
      return 
        fn:string-join($info/*/text(), $InnerDelimiter)
  return
    fn:string-join($lines, $OuterDelimiter)
};
```

Comment: perfect thank you very much , can you please tell me about some resource to get me quickly into xquery concepts and syntax ... I am java based and xquery is some how new to me ... w3schools is very abstract while Priscilla walmsely book is very verbose

Comment: Here are some links that may be of interest for you: http://x-query.com/pipermail/talk/2018-March/005248.html